# Send data to specific client via server

Tags: c, sockets, network-programming

I'm writing a server and two clients in C.  One client is a "slave" type of client that receives commands and the other is a "master" type client that sends commands.  I want to have multiple instances of the slave connected to the server and be able to send a command to a specific slave from the master via the server.

My question is how do I specify the client I want to send the command to?

Here is a very basic example of my server (without error checking)
My actual server has error checking and such, but it's too long to post (and wouldn't compile anyway for anyone because there are dependencies on other files in my project)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

int server_portnumber = 51739;

int main() {
  int listenFD;
  int connectFD;
  socklen_t length;
  struct sockaddr_in s1;
  struct sockaddr_in s2;

  listenFD = socket( AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0 );
  memset( &s1, 0, sizeof( s1 ) );
  s1.sin_family = AF_INET;
  s1.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
  s1.sin_port = server_portnumber;

  bind( listenFD , (struct sockaddr*) &s1 , sizeof( s1 ) );

  length = sizeof( s1 );
  getsockname( listenFD ,  (struct sockaddr*) &s1 , &length );
  listen( listenFD , 512 );

  signal( SIGCHLD , SIG_IGN );

  while(1) {
    length = sizeof( s2 );
    connectFD = accept( listenFD , (struct sockaddr*) &s2 , &length );
    if( !fork() ){
      close( listenFD );
      int select = 0;
      while( read( connectFD , &select, sizeof( int ) ) ) {
        switch( select ) {
          case 10:
            // opcode
            break;
          case 20:
            // command
            break;
          default:
            break;
        }
      }
      close( connectFD );
      exit(0);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please show code that actually compiles, and demonstrates the problem you want help with. This code is full of mismatched parens and braces, arguments of the wrong type (e.g., passing an int instead of a pointer for the addrlen to `getsockname` and `accept`), obvious missing code (if you don't call `htons` somewhere to get your port number, your code isn't going to work on, say, any Intel box), less obvious missing code (your `fork` loop had better not just end like that… and if you get an error from `accept`, you really just ignore it and get the same error over and over as fast as possible?)

Comment: I've updated the code in the OP.  Sorry, I just pulled out code from my actual server to give an example since it's too much to post here (and it has a lot of dependencies on other files in my project)  I didn't include error checking in this example for brevity sake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign each client an ID, give the master some way of knowing about those IDs, and give the server some way to map from IDs to sockets.

That "some way" is pretty vague… because there are endless possibilities, all with different design implications. For example, you could refer to clients by:

- Socket fd.
- Peer address (host and port).
- Auto-numbered index.
- Connection time.
- Randomly-generated key.
- Key received from client during some login step in your protocol.

For most of these, you'll have to tell the master that a new client is available with the relevant ID. When the master wants to send a message to a particular client, it'll send that ID back, which means you'll need some kind of map (just an array if it's something simple like the fd or an auto-index; probably a hash table or balanced tree if it's some arbitrary string) to look up IDs and get fds.

To make this more concrete, consider a chat protocol, like IRC but a lot simpler.

When you first connect, nobody can talk to you, and you can't talk to anyone else.

The server maintains a hash table to map nicknames to socket fds.

When you send a `/nick NICKNAME` command, where `NICKNAME` is a valid nickname (say, any sequence of up to 20 letters and numbers that nobody else is using yet), the server adds an entry to the hash table mapping your nickname to your fd, and sends a message to everyone saying "NICKNAME joined".

When you send a `/msg NICKNAME MESSAGE` command, the server looks up `NICKNAME` in the hash table. If it finds it, it sends MESSAGE to the socket with the corresponding fd.

Comment: I tried saving the socketFD (returned from accept() ) in an indexed array, but when I print out the FD for each new client that connects it is always the same.  Am I saving the wrong FD here?

Comment: @PseudoPsyche: Well, the code that you've given isn't even remotely close to compiling (mismatched braces and parens, wrong argument types to `accept`, etc.), and it doesn't have anything called `socketFD` anywhere, which makes it very hard for anyone to debug it for you…

Comment: @PseudoPsyche: Is it possible that you're connecting a client, closing it, then connecting a new one? Besides the fact that fd's can be recycled once they're closed, there's a very bad bug in your forking design: when the child process's `while` loop ends (because the socket closes), it doesn't exit, it goes back to the outer `while` loop, meaning that every closed child ends up trying to `accept` at the same time…

Comment: Updated code in the OP.  Sorry, I was just trying to put down a basic example of my server and missed some key parts.  I also omitted error checking here for brevity sake.  Also, the slave clients are not disconnecting because after they connect they enter a while(1) loop and try to read data from the socket connection, waiting for commands from the server.

Comment: @PseudoPsyche: So if someone pulls the power cord, they still won't ever disconnect?

Comment: No, if the client read fails it breaks out.  If the server were to go offline, then the read would fail causing the client to exit.

Comment: OK, unlike your original code, your new code has the parent do a `close(connectFD)` on each new socket immediately. Besides meaning that the `fd` in question is now available to be reassigned, that _also_ means that, even if you _did_ have some way of identifying a client, you wouldn't be able to send it a message anyway, because you don't have an fd for its socket.

Comment: As a suggestion, it might be a lot simpler to do what you're trying to do with either a threaded server (very similar, except wrap the `if (!fork())` body in a function and call `pthread_create` with it instead), or a `select` loop. Either way, you don't have to understand issues about how files and other things are shared across processes.

Comment: Ah, so I literally only want that to be closed if the child exits (client disconnects). OP code look good for that now?  I'm gonna go make that change and try it out.

Comment: @PseudoPsyche: There's still at least one problem there—if you don't call `htons` anywhere, you're going to be listening on port 7114 instead of 51739 (unless you're running on a PowerPC or some other big-endian box). But other than that, it looks like it should be good enough for experimenting, at least.

Comment: Okay, that did it!  Thanks.  Alright, I'll look into htons.  I'm just playing around on localhost at the moment, but eventually I want to ensure it works remotely. Also, what benefit would pthreads or a select loop have over fork?

Comment: @PseudoPsyche: TCP/IP headers are in big-endian order. The code to build address structs doesn't do any byte-swapping, so you have to call `htons` on any shorts and `htonl` on any longs that you pass in. Often, the port (which is a short) is the only value you need to worry about, because everything else is either a string or bytes, neither of which needs swapping.

Comment: @PseudoPsyche: The benefit of pthreads or select over fork is that you only have one process, so the listener and all of the client connections are all sharing file descriptors. (They're also sharing global variables, etc., which can be as dangerous as it is convenient. But in your design, there are no mutable shared variables at all, which avoids all the danger.)